# Log Into Website, Download File

Tags: python, pdf, cookies, download

I'm trying to use a python script to log into my school's website and then download the homework assignment PDFs that are uploaded once a week. I've successfully downloaded PDFs from normal, non-protected websites, but I'm having trouble understanding the mechanics of cookies. I've done a bunch of googling, but the only code I've found is the following.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()

username = 'example@gmail.com'
password = '*****'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener.open('http-this.pdf', login_data)
testfile.retrieve("http-path-to-file")
```

Basically, I've tried putting in all the appropriate information, but it didn't work, and I have no idea how to manipulate the code to make it do what I want. How can I use python to log into the website and then download a pdf?

*Edit*
Okay, here's the new code I've got that sort of works, but it outputs a copy of the site's html code with a .pdf extension instead of the file that I'm actually trying to download from the site. What's going wrong?

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
data = {"login":"MYLOG", "password":"*****"}
url = "https://website.php"
url2 = "https://path-to-pdf.pdf"

r2 = s.post(url, data=data)
s.get(url2)
r = s.get(url2)
with open("204_HW.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Use `requests.Session()` , it's much easier

Comment: Okay, that was really helpful, definitely a step in the right direction. I'll tack on the updated code in my original question. Now I've gotten it to save a pdf file generally where I want it, but when I try to open it, it gives me a "file corrupted" error. What do I need to change?